# Delete previously added element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, tablesorter

[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8cg4f/625/)

I want to add extra rows via AJAX to a table using tablesorter with filter and sticky header plugins. I can remove all AJAX rows by adding a class to them and using  `$('.row_selector').empty();`. But I want to have another button that only deletes just the previously added row. Is there any way to do that?

I've this with no success:

```
$('.undo').click(function(){ 
    if ($('.tablesorter tbody tr').length > 1)
        {
           $(this).closest('tr').empty();               
        }; 
});
```

jQuery:

```
$('.undo').click(function(){  //Remove previously added row
    if ($('.tablesorter tbody tr').length > 1)
        {
           $(this).closest('tr').empty();               
        }; 
});

$('.remove').click(function(){

    $('.trremove').empty();
    $(".tablesorter").trigger("update");
});

var ajax_request;
function add_Data() {
    $('.area button').click(function(){
    var colspan = $("table.tablesorter tbody tr").length;
            console.log(colspan);
            if(colspan > 10)
            {
                alert("Too Many Rows");
                return false;
            }
          var source = $(this).data('feed');
          if(typeof ajax_request !== 'undefined')
        ajax_request.abort();
        ajax_request =   
        $.ajax({
    url: source,
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {         
         var title = item.title,
          year = item.year, 
          job = item.Job,
          education = item.Education,
          background = item.Background,
          ingredient = item.Ingredient;
         $(".tablesorter tbody").append('<tr style="display:table-row;" class="trremove"><td>'+education+'</td><td>'+background+'</td><td>'+job+'</td><td>'+ingredient+'</td><td>'+year+'</td><td>'+background+'</td><td>'+year+'</td></tr>');

         });
        },
    });
          $("table").trigger("update"); 

            var sorting = [[2,1],[0,0]]; 
            $(".tablesorter").trigger("sorton",[sorting]); 
        }); 
        return false; 
};

add_Data();
```

HTML:

```
<button class="undo">Remove Previous</button>
<button class="remove">Remove</button>
<div class="area"><button>Class B</button></div>
<div class="area"><button>Class C</button></div>
<div class="area"><button>Class D</button></div>


<table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="1">
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="visibility:hidden;">first name</th> 
   <th>first name</th>
   <th>last name</th>
   <th>age</th>
   <th>total</th>
   <th>discount</th>
   <th>date</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you just want to remove that last row from table..?

Comment: @TJ Yes, I guess deleting the last row has the same effect

Comment: Wouldn't `$('.trremove').empty();` just remove the cells but leave the tr behind?  You may want to use `.remove()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a sorter I would have a global var of `lastAdded`, then in you ajax call you can set it doing this in your success function:

```
lastAdded = $('<tr style="display:table-row;" class="trremove"></tr>').html('<td>'+education+'</td><td>'+background+'</td><td>'+job+'</td><td>'+ingredient+'</td><td>'+year+'</td><td>'+background+'</td><td>'+year+'</td>');
$(".tablesorter tbody").append(lasstAdded);
```

Then in your undo you can just use

```
if (lastAdded != null) {
    lastAdded.remove();
}
```

[Updated fiddle as example (doesn't work as original doesn't work - just to show code)](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/8cg4f/626/)

If you don't want a global class, you can try using an extra class:

In you success:

```
 $('.lastadded').removeClass('lastadded');
 $(".tablesorter tbody").append('<tr style="display:table-row;" class="trremove lastadded"><td>'+education+'</td><td>'+background+'</td><td>'+job+'</td><td>'+ingredient+'</td><td>'+year+'</td><td>'+background+'</td><td>'+year+'</td></tr>');
```

In your undo

```
$('.lastadded').remove();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/8cg4f/627/)

Comment: Do you think there's an extra `tr` added by tablesorter? I added `    $('.tablesorter tbody tr:last').addClass('lastadded');` in the Undo button so that I can keep deleting the last row. Sometimes it takes a few extra clicks to remove a row. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8cg4f/631/)

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/8cg4f/634/, but yeah if you look at the classes in the inspect element, they seem to be incrementing in 2s so there must be an extra row being added somewhere

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the last row from table, you can try the following:

```
$('.undo').click(function(){ 
 if ($('.tablesorter tbody tr').length > 1)
    {
       $('.tablesorter tbody tr:last').remove();               
    }; 
});
```

Comment: assumes no sorting has occurred

Comment: @charlietfl OP mentioned that deleting last row has the same effect in comments...

Comment: @TJ It doesn't seem to be always working. I have to make quite a few extra clicks to remove the rows. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cg4f/625/)

Comment: @user35295 that fiddle isn't working because you've errors in your code… check the console.. function `table sorter` is undefined… if you're using a plugin, you've to either add an online link to it in external resources option or if it's not available, copy paste the whole source code in jsfiddle.. can you make a working fiddle where we can add rows..?